# wpf gradient brush that spans multiple elements

Tags: wpf, background, gradient, radial-gradients

Suppose there is an element with irregular shape composed of other elements with arbitrary nesting:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="brush">
    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
  </RadialGradientBrush>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Name="element">
  <StackPanel.Effect>
    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="10" />
  </StackPanel.Effect>
  <Rectangle Name="child1" Height="100" Margin="10" Stroke="Black" Fill="{StaticResource brush}" />
  <Grid>
    <Rectangle Name="child2" Height="100" Margin="10" Stroke="Black" Fill="{StaticResource brush}" />
  </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

All parts are interactive (i.e a child can be a real control).

How can I fill backgrounds of children with a single radial gradient that spans all of them (should look like as if it is sized to `element`).

UPDATE: StackPanel has a shadow which should be drawn around children.

[image: bad][image: good]

One possible solution is to generate gradients with Radius and Origin/Center bound to `element`'s and `child`'s properties with appropriate conversions, but such approach would be rather complex and expensive.

Comment: Can you make the actual controls themselves `Transparent` and put them on a background?

Comment: What do you mean ? Maybe provide an example.

Comment: So you could create a `DockPanel` with your gradient background, and then put your controls inside that `DockPanel` (as children).

Comment: But I need to "cut out" empty space between controls.

Comment: I thought you might, that's why I asked.  You could fake that cut out, but it's probably not the optimal solution for you.

Comment: I have added shadows around component to illustrate why faking cut is not really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I went with transformed gradients route except instead of bindings and converters I was able to elegantly solve it by creating background `Transformation` in `ArrangeOverride` of child elements and exposing it via dependency property.
Actual `RadialGradientBrush` binds its `Transform` to `BackgroundTransform` by searching for ancestor with matching type.

This assumes that one can modify/wrap child classes which is true in my case. It can be made more flexible with attached properties and a bit more work.

Actual code is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mwisnicki/4953452/).